Suspend isn't working on ASUS ROG Strix G18 G814JIR (2024)
I recently purchased an ASUS ROG Strix G18 G814JIR (2024) laptop. I received laptop with Windows already installed. I checked the laptop's performance on Windows, and all components were working well, including the sound output. I I decided to setup a dual boot (Windows and Ubuntu). I installed Ubuntu without any problems.
I tried to suspend the laptop and sometimes experience that getting out of suspend mouse cursor becomes move slowly on UI elements. I also have this issue when disconnecting the laptop from the charger. This exists for around 5 seconds and becomes normal. It's hard to work in this mode, because the mouse is just slowing down. I tried different ways to fix  this issue, helps only reinstall of current driver.
Other graphics drivers can't be installed, every time I receive errors. X.Org X Server is terrible, I can't work with it.
System info:

Current graphics driver:

Graphics card details:
0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake-S UHD Graphics (rev 04)
0000:01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation AD106M [GeForce RTX 4070 Max-Q / Mobile] (rev a1)

List of playback hardware devices:
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC294 Analog [ALC294 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0


Try the 555 or the 555-open for your 4070. They do offer some improvements over the 535. What errors do you get when trying to install them?

Tried to install 555, fortunately successfully this time. Also applied config for turning off/on nvidia services at the time of suspend/suspend exit. Still persists a little lag with cursor at time of charge disconnect.
